# Language switcher

Tags: ios, iphone

I am developing an simple app for iOS. I have already developed this app for Android and in Android version I needed to implement in app language switcher. It was due to a fact that some Android devices (from specific countries) doesnt containt all languages and therefore users weren't able to change app language by changing system language. This is the reason why I needed to implement in app language switcher to override system language and allow, for example, users from slovakia to chose slovak language even that theirs phone didnt have it.

My question is: Do I need to implement this functionality on iPhone too? Or does every iphone contain all languages. If so then I can totaly rely on system language and I dont need to implement in app language switching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an iOS device and you see the required language there, you may be sure this language exists on all other iOS devices in the world.